# How to generate list of documents directly in MongoDB's shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I don't wanna use any other language. Just open the MongoDB's shell and create let say 100 000 documents with _id incremented by 1.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB shell is a javascript shell, so you can use anything you can use in javascript:

```
> for (var i=0; i<100000; i++) { db.my_collection.insert({i: i}); }
```